# Select Query ArrayList java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Tags: android, sqlite, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting this error:

> "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0".

I have DatabaseHelper,Select and Insert Classes.So I am trying to get data from DatabaseHelper class to display on Search(Select)Class.I declared "UrunKodu" on DatabaseHelper as Column name but I dont exactly know what to do next to connect this "UrunKodu" declaration on my Search Class.

---

### **This is DatabaseHelper**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Urunler.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "urunler_tablosu";
private static final String COL_2 = "UrunKodu";
private static final String COL_3 = "UrunAdi";
private static final String COL_4 = "Adet";              
private static final String COL_5 = "AlisFiyati";
private static final String COL_6 = "SatisFiyati";
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> YourList = new ArrayList<>();


DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (UrunKodu TEXT,UrunAdi TEXT,Adet REAL,AlisFiyati REAL,SatisFiyati REAL )");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS urunler_tablosu");
    onCreate(db);
}


boolean insertData(String ukodu, String uadi, String adet, String afiyati, String sfiyati){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,ukodu);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,uadi);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,adet);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,afiyati);
    contentValues.put(COL_6,sfiyati);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    return result != -1;
}

//Get all item in your database
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllDatabaseData(String UrunKodu) { // we use the id to find it corresponding user details
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM '" + TABLE_NAME + "' WHERE UrunKodu='" + UrunKodu + "'",null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    while(!res.isAfterLast()){
        HashMap<String, String> array_list = new HashMap<>();
        array_list.put("Urunkodu",res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COL_2)));
        array_list.put("UrunAdi",res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COL_3)));
        array_list.put("Adet",res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COL_4)));
        array_list.put("AlisFiyati",res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COL_5)));
        array_list.put("SatisFiyati",res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COL_6)));
        YourList.add(array_list);
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return YourList;

}
```

}

---

**This is Search(Select Class)**

---

```
public class UrunKontrol extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String >>DataList = new ArrayList<>();
EditText editkontukodu,editkontuadi,editkontadet,editkontafiyati,editkontsfiyati;
Button arabuton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_urun_kontrol);

    editkontukodu = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kontrolbarkodno);
    editkontuadi = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kontrolurunadi);
    editkontadet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kontrolurunadeti);
    editkontafiyati = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kontrolurunalisfiyati);
    editkontsfiyati = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kontrolurunsatisfiyati);
    arabuton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.aramabutonu);
    arabuton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DataList = new DatabaseHelper(UrunKontrol.this).getAllDatabaseData(UrunKodu);   //Here I am getting error
            editkontuadi.setText(DataList.get(0).get("UrunAdi"));
            editkontadet.setText(DataList.get(0).get("Adet"));
            editkontafiyati.setText(DataList.get(0).get("AlisFiyati"));
            editkontsfiyati.setText(DataList.get(0).get("SatisFiyati"));
        }
    });

}
```

}

---

**This is Insert class**

---

```
public class Urunkayit extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText editkayitbarkodno,editkontrolurunadi,editkontrolurunadeti,editkontrolurunalisfiyati,editkontrolurunsatisfiyati;
Button kaydetbuton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_urunkayit);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    editkayitbarkodno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kayitbarkodno);
    editkontrolurunadi = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kayiturunadi);
    editkontrolurunadeti = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kayiturunadeti);
    editkontrolurunalisfiyati = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kayiturunalisfiyati);
    editkontrolurunsatisfiyati = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kayiturunsatisfiyati);
    kaydetbuton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kayitbutonu);

    urunKaydetme();

}
public void urunKaydetme(){
    kaydetbuton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editkayitbarkodno.getText().toString(),
                            editkontrolurunadi.getText().toString(),
                            editkontrolurunadeti.getText().toString(),
                            editkontrolurunalisfiyati.getText().toString(),
                            editkontrolurunsatisfiyati.getText().toString());
                    if (isInserted = true){
                        Toast.makeText(Urunkayit.this,"Ürün Kaydedildi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        editkayitbarkodno.setText("");
                        editkontrolurunadi.setText("");
                        editkontrolurunadeti.setText("");
                        editkontrolurunalisfiyati.setText("");
                        editkontrolurunsatisfiyati.setText("");

                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(Urunkayit.this,"Ürün Kaydedilemedi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

}

---

### I dont know how to declare them(size and UrunKodu) in search class

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataList` returns empty list, check size before accessing it

```
arabuton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        DataList = new DatabaseHelper(UrunKontrol.this).getAllDatabaseData(UrunKodu);   //Here I am getting error
        if(DataList.size > 0){
          editkontuadi.setText(DataList.get(0).get("UrunAdi"));
          editkontadet.setText(DataList.get(0).get("Adet"));
          editkontafiyati.setText(DataList.get(0).get("AlisFiyati"));
          editkontsfiyati.setText(DataList.get(0).get("SatisFiyati"));
        }
    }
});
```

**Note** : Also debug that the value you are trying to fetch is exist in database

Comment: I am very new to these. Can you tell me how am I going to do them?

Answer (score 0):

Complete example with code of database as you desire and insert, view and search functionality which is properly working and tested.

Total 6 java files and 4 layout files.

1.Database.java

```
public class Database {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Urunler";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "urunler_tablosu";
public static final int DATABSE_VERSION = 1;


public static final String URUNKODU = "UrunKodu";
public static final String URUNADI = "UrunAdi";
public static final String ADET = "Adet";
public static final String ALISFIYATI = "AlisFiyati";
public static final String SATISFIYATI = "SatisFiyati";


//to create a table
private static final String TABLE_CREATE_URUNLER_TABLOSU = "create table urunler_tablosu(UrunKodu TEXT,UrunAdi TEXT,Adet REAL,AlisFiyati REAL,SatisFiyati REAL);";

private Context context;
SQLiteDatabase db;    // manipulation with database
DatabaseHelper dbhelper;

public Database(Context ctx) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = ctx;
    dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
}


//SQLITEOpenHelper has methods to creae and open
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //DatabaseHelper's constructor will create the database
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABSE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_URUNLER_TABLOSU);
        Log.d("table is created..", "URUNLER_TABLOSU");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }


}


public Database Open() throws SQLException {
    db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void Close() {
    dbhelper.close();
}

//==== as mapping REAL in sql is float in java =================
public long insertData(String UrunKodu, String UrunAdi, float Adet, float AlisFiyati, float SatisFiyati) {
    ContentValues initialvalues = new ContentValues();

    initialvalues.put(URUNKODU, UrunKodu);
    initialvalues.put(URUNADI, UrunAdi);
    initialvalues.put(ADET, Adet + "");
    initialvalues.put(ALISFIYATI, AlisFiyati + "");
    initialvalues.put(SATISFIYATI, SatisFiyati + "");

    Log.d(URUNKODU, UrunKodu + "");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, initialvalues);

}

public Cursor getAllData() {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Log.d("gks query=", query + "");
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return cur;
}

}
```

2.POJOUrunKodu.java

```
public class POJOUrunKodu {

String UrunKodu, UrunAdi,  Adet,  AlisFiyati,  SatisFiyati;

public POJOUrunKodu(String urunKodu, String urunAdi, String adet, String alisFiyati, String satisFiyati) {
    UrunKodu = urunKodu;
    UrunAdi = urunAdi;
    Adet = adet;
    AlisFiyati = alisFiyati;
    SatisFiyati = satisFiyati;
}
}
```

3.CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<POJOUrunKodu> _data;
Context _c;

CustomAdapter( Context c,ArrayList<POJOUrunKodu> data) {
    _data = data;
    _c = c;
    Log.d("inside customAdapter", "inside customAdapter constructor...");
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return _data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return _data.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) _c
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.entityurunkodu, null);
    }

    TextView tvlist_urunKodu = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvlist_urunKodu);
    TextView tvlist_urunAdi = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvlist_urunAdi);
    TextView tvlist_adet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvlist_adet);
    TextView tvlist_alisFiyati = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvlist_alisFiyati);
    TextView tvlist_satisFiyati = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvlist_satisFiyati);

    Log.d("tvcredit==>", " "+tvlist_urunAdi.getText().toString());

    POJOUrunKodu tpj = _data.get(position);
    tvlist_urunKodu.setText(tpj.UrunKodu+"");
    tvlist_urunAdi.setText(tpj.UrunAdi+"");
    tvlist_adet.setText(tpj.Adet+"");
    tvlist_alisFiyati.setText(tpj.AlisFiyati+"");
    tvlist_satisFiyati.setText(tpj.SatisFiyati+"");

    return v;
}

}
```

4.InsertActivity.java

```
public class InsertActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText edt_UrunKodu, edt_UrunAdi, edt_Adet, edt_AlisFiyati, edt_SatisFiyati;

Button btn_insert;

Database db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert);


    //======== findviewbyid starts ======
    edt_UrunKodu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_UrunKodu);
    edt_UrunAdi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_UrunAdi);
    edt_Adet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_Adet);
    edt_AlisFiyati = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_AlisFiyati);
    edt_SatisFiyati = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_SatisFiyati);

    btn_insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_insert);
    //======== findviewbyid ends ======


    db=new Database(getApplicationContext());
    db.Open();
    db.Close();

    btn_insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (edt_UrunKodu.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0 ||
                    edt_UrunAdi.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0 ||
                    edt_Adet.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0 ||
                    edt_AlisFiyati.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0 ||
                    edt_SatisFiyati.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {

                String sUrunKodu=edt_UrunKodu.getText().toString().trim();
                String sUrunAdi=edt_UrunAdi.getText().toString().trim();
                String sAdet=edt_Adet.getText().toString().trim();
                String sAlisFiyati=edt_AlisFiyati.getText().toString().trim();
                String sSatisFiyati=edt_SatisFiyati.getText().toString().trim();


                db.Open();
                db.insertData(sUrunKodu,sUrunAdi,Float.parseFloat(sAdet),Float.parseFloat(sAlisFiyati),Float.parseFloat(sSatisFiyati));
                db.Close();

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

5.SearchViewActivity.java

```
public class SearchViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText edt_search;
ListView lv_data;

Database db;

ArrayList<POJOUrunKodu> arrayListUrunKodu;
ArrayList<POJOUrunKodu> arrayListUrunKodu_search;

CustomAdapter customAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_view);


    edt_search=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_search);
    lv_data=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_data);

    db=new Database(getApplicationContext());
    db.Open();
    db.Close();

    load_all_data();

    edt_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String text = s.toString();
            filter(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });



}


public void load_all_data()
{
    arrayListUrunKodu=new ArrayList<>();
    arrayListUrunKodu_search=new ArrayList<>();
    db.Open();

    Cursor cur=db.getAllData();

    if(cur.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {

            String sUrunKodu=cur.getString(0);
            String sUrunAdi=cur.getString(1);
            String sAdet=cur.getString(2);
            String sAlisFiyati=cur.getString(3);
            String sSatisFiyati=cur.getString(4);

            arrayListUrunKodu.add(new POJOUrunKodu(sUrunKodu,sUrunAdi,sAdet,sAlisFiyati,sSatisFiyati));
            arrayListUrunKodu_search.add(new POJOUrunKodu(sUrunKodu,sUrunAdi,sAdet,sAlisFiyati,sSatisFiyati));

        }while (cur.moveToNext());
    }

    cur.close();
    db.Close();

    customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(SearchViewActivity.this,arrayListUrunKodu);
    lv_data.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}

// =========Filter method starts=======
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    Log.d("filter",charText+"");
    arrayListUrunKodu.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        arrayListUrunKodu.addAll(arrayListUrunKodu_search);
        Log.d("data","all");
        Log.d("data size=",arrayListUrunKodu.size()+"");
    } else {
        for (POJOUrunKodu pod : arrayListUrunKodu_search) {

            if (pod.UrunKodu.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)||
                    pod.UrunAdi.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                arrayListUrunKodu.add(pod);
            }

        }
        Log.d("data","filter");
        Log.d("filter size=",arrayListUrunKodu.size()+"");
    }
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
}
```

6.MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn_insert_data,btn_search_view_data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    btn_insert_data=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_insert_data);
    btn_search_view_data=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_search_view_data);


    btn_insert_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent_insert=new Intent(MainActivity.this,InsertActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent_insert);
        }
    });

    btn_search_view_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent_insert=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent_insert);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Layout Files are here,For customadapter this entity file is needed

1.entityurunkodu.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvlist_urunKodu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#f00"
    ></TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvlist_urunAdi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#789"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    ></TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvlist_adet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#00f"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    ></TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvlist_alisFiyati"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#f0f"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    ></TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvlist_satisFiyati"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    ></TextView>
```

==content_search_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".SearchViewActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_search_view"
android:orientation="vertical">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="seach urunkodu"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#f00"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

=====content_insert.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".InsertActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_insert"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_UrunKodu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="UrunKodu"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_UrunAdi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="UrunAdi"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_Adet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Adet"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_AlisFiyati"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="AlisFiyati"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_SatisFiyati"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="SatisFiyati"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_insert"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="INSERT"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

=====activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_insert_data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="INSERT DATA"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="#f00"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_search_view_data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search and View DATA"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="#00f"/>
```

So, it's perfectly working code with xml files and java files and activity files.
you may addes content and activity as may as you required. anywhere for alignment you can use ALT+CLTR+L for in android studio. sure it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need the functionality of the app like I tried to write.I am gonna use Barcode scanner device and its functionalities are read,write,press enter.So what I want is after I write the product code to "editurunkodu" I'm gonna press enter.Then the required items about the product will be shown on other edittexts.

Comment: i mean that after enter product, will you have any alert dialog with list?

Comment: I would like to see something like "product is not in the database" otherwise I just want to place the items to edittexts.

Comment: how products has been come?

Comment: They don't :D I want to do it but I dont know how to do it :) How am I gonna place the results to edittexts?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: actually clearly mention that how your data is came either from json or from db

Comment: Are you asking me how do I fetch data in my version ? what is json?

Comment: in given example, you can insert data from one button and you can retrive data from another button and search it. it is checked and properly run example.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but this way doesnt support my needs.Can you tell me what is the connection  between customadapter and searchview activity.How can I convert listview to edittexts?

Comment: Connection between customAdapter and searchView to filter the data as per searching criteria.
in given complete example there is no searchView, only use of EditText for searching, just go through all the code and implement it. feel free to contact.

Comment: I also want to get the results to edittexts.In this example I'm getting via listview right?